# Can I decrease the sampling interval and still have accurate results?

Tags: confidence-interval, sampling, monte-carlo, uncertainty, threshold

A company has been collecting water chemistry data annually for 20+ years to monitor water quality. Now they're wondering if they can decrease their sampling interval to once every 2 or 3 years and still detect exceedances when they occur. What would be the best approach to assess this? My first instinct is to use a Monte Carlo simulation to look at every 2/3 year sampling interval combination in their 20+ year dataset and see how much it deviated from the "true" annual measure, and then calculate how many exceedances it missed detecting. But I understand that a Monte Carlo usually needs 1000's of combinations to run effectively and I would only have 10-20 possible combinations. Is it still possible to determine this with a different analysis? I also thought a Bayesian analysis might be appropriate, but I think that would require a very deep understanding of the interaction between the various water chemistry variables and how their changes affect one another.

Or is it more about uncertainty? For instance I can say "If you're sampling annually you have an X% chance of detecting an exceedance if it occurs, if you're sampling every 2 years you have a Y% chance, and if you sample every 3 years you have a Z% chance"?

Comment: I have performed such analyses many times. What can make them work is an underlying conceptual model, supported by auxiliary data if possible, that gives quantitative information about the duration of any exceedance once it occurs. You also need to consider the risk associated with overlooking exceedances, which relates to the time needed to respond and the potential harm to any exposed population (human or ecological).  In the 1980's, groundwater scientists studied this question and proposed using the lag-1 autocorrelation in pristine environments. That "very deep understanding" is crucial.

Comment: @whuber Can you point me towards any published studies that have done this and demonstrated the statistical rigor of their approach? My previous experience with models of this nature (mainly focused on predicting future fish stocks) has been that they're nice best guesses, but often very error prone, even when executed by experts with a very deep understanding of the underlying biology-- just because it's computationally very difficult for people to predict if/how natural ecosystems will self-correct themselves under various circumstances.

Comment: The guidance I was referring to is Barcelona *et al.*, [Sampling Frequency For Groundwater Quality Monitoring (1989).](https://nepis.epa.gov/Exe/ZyPURL.cgi?Dockey=2000TTSS.TXT).  Some papers citing it can be found on Google Scholar, but nothing recently.  BTW, what you are asking about are a *model* and a *methodology.*  MC simulation is a *computational procedure* which, by itself, is not going to solve your problem.  The hydrological considerations discussed in Barcelona might be a guide towards conceptualizing and modeling your situation.